# Dropping attributes from scale

Tags: r, dplyr, scale

I'm scaling multiply columns using the `scale()`-function.

How can I extract the scaled values from `scale()` only and drop all attributes?

```
set.seed(5)
data.frame(x1 = runif(10, 1, 5),
           x2 = runif(10, 1, 5),
           x3 = runif(10, 1, 5)) |>
 mutate(across(.cols = num_range('x', 1:3),
               .fns = scale,
               .names = '{.col}_z')) |>
 str()
```

Returning

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ x1  : num  2.71 3.45 2.91 3.67 1.09 ...
 $ x2  : num  3.33 1.74 2.91 2.05 4.26 ...
 $ x3  : num  1.9 1.44 4.6 1.07 1.68 ...
 $ x1_z: num [1:10, 1] -0.336 0.352 -0.155 0.559 -1.84 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 3.07
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 1.08
 $ x2_z: num [1:10, 1] 0.61 -1.006 0.181 -0.688 1.55 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 2.73
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 0.985
 $ x3_z: num [1:10, 1] -0.672 -0.973 1.079 -1.213 -0.816 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 2.94
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 1.54
```

Comment: Generally the attributes don't hurt anything and there's not a reason to drop them, but if you run `as.numeric` on them it will turn them into plain `numeric` vectors without attributes.

Comment: ^ This can be implemented with `.fns = ~as.numeric(scale(.)),`

Comment: Note also that `scale` returns an `array` not a vector. Hence another option would be to do `.fns = ~scale(.x)[, 1]` to get a vector and to get rid of the attributes too.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `center` and `scale` arguments of the `scale` function are set to `TRUE`.

```
scale(x, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

At the section **Value** of the documentation it states:
`For scale.default, the centered, scaled matrix. The numeric centering and scalings used (if any) are returned as attributes "scaled:center" and "scaled:scale"`

And those attributes are what you see in your output. If you want to exclude the attributes you can slice the output to get the returned matrix and exclude the rest, as by @stefan comment

```
set.seed(5)
data.frame(x1 = runif(10, 1, 5),
           x2 = runif(10, 1, 5),
           x3 = runif(10, 1, 5)) |>
 dplyr::mutate(across(.cols = num_range('x', 1:3),
               .fns = ~scale(.x, center = T, scale = T)[, 1],
               .names = '{.col}_z')) |>
 str()
```

Returning

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ x1  : num  2.78 1.24 2.1 1.12 1.06 ...
 $ x2  : num  4.26 1.94 4.31 3.13 4.72 ...
 $ x3  : num  2.54 3.27 4.69 4.9 4.73 ...
 $ x1_z: num  0.459 -1.082 -0.219 -1.195 -1.262 ...
 $ x2_z: num  0.806 -1.517 0.849 -0.324 1.258 ...
 $ x3_z: num  -0.465 0.261 1.684 1.9 1.728 ...
```

Hope this helps